# Substrate enum to typescript(polkadot-js)

Tags: polkadot-js, typescript

I am new to Substrate and Polkadot-JS. I am attempting to convert this enum with values to TypeScript, but I haven't been successful so far.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

```
pub enum Permission {
    TrustedBy(AccountId),
    SetExchangeRate,
    
}
```